# Gradient descent optimizer minimize

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

I am fairly new to tensorflow. Found this piece of code that trains a model to minimize the loss:

```
loss = -(tf.log(responsible_weight)*reward_holder) 
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
update = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Here 'reward_holder' gives either 1 or -1 depending on a random number. 'responsible_weight' is a float number selected from a placeholder whose value is also related to the random number. My question is what is updated at each step of the tweaking process? Does responsible_weight get 0.01 added or subtracted each time? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow, the goal of training is to update the values of *variables*. In this code, the optimizer updates the variables that make up the `loss` expression. Placeholders are tensors, not variables. So if `responsible_weight` comes from a placeholder, then it's not going to be updated by the training process.